# SVG Polyline Manipulation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, svg, aurelia

I am working with TypeScript 3.1.1 in VS Code with an Aurelia project.  I need to manipulate an SVG Polyline in TypeScript code. I am having trouble creating a new SVGPoint object. My initial HTML looks like this:

```html
<svg class="distance-polyline-svg" width="100%" height="100%" ref="distancePolylineSvg">
    <polyline points="100,100 300,100 200,300 500,300" style="stroke: rgba(6, 28, 129, 0.3); stroke-width: 5; fill: transparent" ref="distancePolyline" />
</svg>
```

*distancePolylineSvg* is declared as *SVGElement*
*distancePolyline* is declared as *SVGPolylineElement*

I can access a point using:

*this.distancePolyline.points.getItem(i);*
But when I try to create a new point to use in *this.distancePolyline.points.replaceItem* or *this.distancePolyline.points.appendItem* I am having no success. I've tried *new SVGPoint()* and get a bad constructor error. I've tried *new DOMPoint()*, which works but when using it in *replaceItem* I get an error stating it is expecting a parameter of type SVGPoint. Casting doesn't work. Neither SVGElement nor SVGPolygonElement have a *createSVGPoint* method and *document.rootElement.createSVGPoint* doesn't work because rootElement is null.

How do I create a new SVGPoint to pass to the SVGPointList methods?

Comment: Hey Tony! I've added the SVG tag because this is more of an svg question. Can you add your code to a gist.run so I can have a closer look. You can start with a template here: https://gist.run/?id=040775f06aba5e955afd362ee60863aa.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve updated the gist.run with typings. https://gist.run/?id=040775f06aba5e955afd362ee60863aa

As Robert mentioned, you need to type your `<svg>` element as an SVGSVGElement.

The SVG DOM API spec currently lacks a method for getting accurately typed SVG elements from HTML DOM ellements, and this in reflected in TypeScript. However, the actual objects returned from the DOM API are in fact SVG DOM elements. Therefore, you need to use a cast on your HTML DOM queries and then manually type them as SVG DOM elements.

```
let svg: SVGSVGElement = <any>document.getElementById('svg');
let polyline: SVGPolylineElement = <any>svg.getElementById('polyline');
let point: SVGPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
point.x = 0;
point.y = 0;
polyline.points.appendItem(point);
```

Using Aurelia’s `element.ref` makes this look a little bit cleaner, though it’s basically doing the same thing for you.

**view**

```
<template>
  <svg element.ref="svg">
    <polyline element.ref="polyline"></polyline>
  </svg>
</template>
```

**view-model**

```
export class SVGViewModel {
  svg: SVGSVGElement;
  polyline: SVGPolylineElement;
  addPoint(x: number, y: number) {
    const point: SVGPoint = this.svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = x
    point.y = y;
    this.polyline.points.appendItem(point)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<svg>` element should be modelled as an SVGSVGElement, they have a [createSVGPoint](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#struct-__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGPoint) method that returns an `SVGPoint object.